# How to get output of a bigquery in a specific json format

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table in this format :

DataProvider,Id,Name,Time

ABC,f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934,"xyz",43200

ABC,f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934,"123",43200

ABC,00453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934,"xyz",43200

I want to generate the output in this format (json) :

{"dataProviderId":"ABC","items":[{"Id":"f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934","data":[{"Name":"xyz","Time":43200},{"Name":"xyz","Time":43200}],
{"Id":"00453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934","data":[{"Name":"xyz","Time":43200}]}

Answer (score 2):

In your `CLI`, you can use `bq` command with `--format` flag, where you can pass `prettyjson` format (easy-to-read JSON format).

```
bq query --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `project_id`:dataset.table' > output.json
```

By using `>` at the end of the command, it is possible to save the output of a command to a new file. You will be able to see the output of query in output.json file.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) json 
FROM (
  SELECT dataProvider, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, data)) items
  FROM (
    SELECT dataProvider, id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, time)) data
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
    GROUP BY dataProvider, id
  )
  GROUP BY dataProvider
) t
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row json     
1   {"dataProvider":"ABC","items":[{"id":"f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934","data":[{"name":"xyz","time":43200},{"name":"123","time":43200}]},{"id":"00453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934","data":[{"name":"xyz","time":43200}]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhail for the help. Unfortunately, I couldn't deploy the solution as Bigquery had a limit on what the max size of the row could be. Got an error that : 
"Output of TO_JSON_STRING exceeds max allowed output size of 128.00M"

I am now trying to deploy this via pandas.